# Reference shell Script within a shell Script in YAML

Tags: bash, shell, yaml, kubernetes-helm

Is there the right way to reference a shell script written within a script in a YAML file? E.g.:

```
    data:
        ex1.sh: |
        #!/bin/bash -x
        . /shellscriptloc/ex2.sh
        ...
        ...
        ...
        ex2.sh: |
        <no bin bash>
```

**The YAML file is part of a helm chart setup that is triggered during helm install and helm hooks**

**The YAML file is imported into a daemon set, and the yaml file presented as a config. in the daemon set, the script is called to execute inside a Kubernetes node. And the script is passed as data from this YAML file**

q1 : is the location reference of ex2.sh correct for using/calling methods defined within ex2.sh :-       **. /shellscriptloc/ex2.sh** this is the current way I tried but causing errors.
q2 : does not defining ex2.sh as bin bash, the right way to go about it? ex2.sh contains functions that can be called are used within ex1.sh

Comment: Please read description of `linux` and `linux-kernel` tags and then remove them from your question.

Comment: I can understand removing linux-kernel, but linux is the general tag, covering shell script, and programming / code. Linux-kernel removed. Thanks for notifying. @Cyrus

Comment: This question is impossible to answer unless we know what is processing the YAML file. Can you provide more details?

Comment: @larsks The YAML file is part of a helm chart setup that is triggered during helm install and helm hooks. Question edited. apologies for missing out the info on this

Comment: YAML by itself has no idea of "shell scripts". This seems to be a problem related only to _helm_.

Comment: @user1934428 regardless of helm, what is the generic way to reference a script within a script? If there's a way or can it be just skipped?

Comment: The YAML file is just data.  You could put anything inside that multi-line string (YAML block scalar).  If this is in a Helm context, I might tell you the actual right answer is to `COPY` the script into the image you're running.  How does this YAML file get turned into Kubernetes manifests, and how are the other files related?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by _to reference_ a script. Given that scripts essentially are executable programs, it makes sense to ask how to execute one program from within a different program, but as YAML is not a programming language, this does not make sense here either.

Comment: @DavidMazethank you for your reply. The YAML file is imported into a daemon set, and the yaml file presented as a config. in the daemon set, the script is called to execute inside a Kubernetes node. And  the script is passed as data from this YAML file.

Comment: Well, as I said before, the problem is solely restricted to _helm_, which I unfortunately don't know. However, Stackoverflow provides the tag _kubernetes-helm_. I suggest that you replace all your tags with this kubernetes-helm tag, and repost the question on [su], because it is unrelated to programming and therefore not suitable for Stackoverflow anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The line following a block style literal scalar indicator (`|`) should be indented, unless that scalar is in itself a YAML document. Without that indentation the YAML parser would not know when the literal scalar ends:

```
    data:
        ex1.sh: |
          #!/bin/bash -x
          . /shellscriptloc/ex2.sh
          ...
          ...
          ...
        ex2.sh: |
          <no bin bash>
```